# Sharing Data between Views in Swift/better approach for this?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am brand new to Swift and SwiftUi, decided to pick it up for fun over the summer to put on my resume. As a college student, my first idea to get me started was a Check calculator to find out what each person on the check owes the person who paid. Right now I have an intro screen and then a new view to a text box to add the names of the people that ordered off the check. I stored the names in an array and wanted to next do a new view that asks for-each person that was added, what was their personal total? I am struggling with sharing data between different structs and such. Any help would be greatly appreciated, maybe there is a better approach without multiple views? Anyways, here is my code (spacing a little off cause of copy and paste):

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                
                Image("RestaurantPhoto1").ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    
                    Text("TabCalculator")
                        
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        
                        .padding(.bottom, 150.0)
                    
                    
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                        
                        destination: Page2(),
                        
                        label: {
                            
                            Text("Get Started!").font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(Color.white).padding().background(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=View@*/Color.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            
                        })
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}



struct Page2: View {
    
    @State var nameArray = [String]()
    
    @State var name: String = ""
    
    @State var numberOfPeople = 0
    
    @State var personTotal = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                TextField("Enter name", text: $name, onCommit: addName).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()).padding()
                List(nameArray, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            
            .navigationBarTitle("Group")
        }
    }
    
    func addName() {
        
        let newName = name.capitalized.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        guard newName.count > 0 else {
            
            return
            
        }
        nameArray.append(newName)
        name = ""
        
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        
        Group {
            
            ContentView()
            ContentView()
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a good point to go through some SwiftUI tutorials and get the basics under your belt. A good and popular one is https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui

Comment: With SwiftUI it is particularly important to understand the separation of your views and your model.  `@State` and `@Binding` properties are ok for simple or local values but you need a separate model for your whole app data.

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple level for passing data between views in SwiftUI. Each one has its best use cases.

- Static init properties
- Binding properties
- Environment Objects

**Static init properties.**
You're probably used to that, it's just passing constants through your view init function like this :

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyView2(title: "Hello, world!")
    }
}

struct MyView2: View {
    let title: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
    }
}
```

**Binding properties.**
These enables you to pass data between a parent view and child. Parent can pass the value to the child on initialization and updates of this value and child view can update the value itself (which receives too).

```
struct MyView: View {
    // State properties stored locally to MyView
    @State private var title: String

    var body: some View {
        // Points the MyView2's "title" binding property to the local title state property using "$" sign in front of the property name.
        MyView2(title: $title)
    }
}

struct MyView2: View {
    @Binding var title: String
    var body: some View {
        // Textfield presents the same value as it is stored in MyView.
        // It also can update the title according to what the user entered with keyboard (which updates the value stored in MyView.
        TextField("My title field", text: $title)
    }
}
```

**Environment Objects.**
Those works in the same idea as Binding properties but the difference is : it passes the value globally through all children views. However, the property is to be an "ObservableObject" which comes from the Apple Combine API. It works like this :

```
// Your observable object
class MyViewManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var title: String

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    // Store your Observable object in the parent View
    @StateObject var manager = MyViewManager(title: "")

    var body: some View {
        MyView2()
            // Pass the manager to MyView2 and its children
            .environmentObject(manager)
    }
}

struct MyView2: View {
    // Read and Write access to parent environment object
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: MyViewManager

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Read and write to the manager title property
            TextField("My title field", text: $manager.title)
            MyView3()
                // .environmentObject(manager)
                // No need to pass the environment object again, it is passed by inheritance.
        }
    }
}

struct MyView3: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: MyViewManager

    var body: some View {
        TextField("My View 3 title field", text: $manager.title)
    }
}
```

Hope it was helpful. If it is, don't forget to mark this answer as the right one

For others that are reading this to get a better understanding, don't forget to upvote by clicking on the arrow up icon